# Gradians to degrees with zero

Tags: qgis, convert, angles

I want rotate symbol, but the angle is in gradians (grade, gon) with zero on east.
How to convert this angle to degrees with zero on north ?
[image: how to convert]

I try (angle*0.9 + 90), but e.g. for angle with 380 gon => 432 degrees not 72°. Any solution ?

Comment: You mean 342° not 432°? (360*380/400 )

Comment: To convert gradian to degree, I divise by 0.9. I try to add 90° to find the zero on north, but I know it's not the solution.

Comment: But 1 grad is 0.9° so you have to actually *multiply* your grad value by 0.9 to get the degree equivalent, not divide it. That's what I meant.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I multiply 400 gon = 360° so 400*0.9=360. It's not division. In my example : 380*0.9= 342° + 90 = 432°. the problem is origin of angle, east and not north.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for using the [modulo operator](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/modulo-operation.html) to "reset" values after they pass a certain threshold. The modulo operator is represented by `%` in the QGIS expression builder and returns the remainder after dividing the numerator by the denominator.

The following expression will convert `"gon"` to degrees, add 90 degrees (to account for the change in direction), and any results over 360 will get "reset" to the equivalent angle starting from 0.

```
(("gon"*0.9)+90)%360
```

So for example:

- 100 gon = 90 degrees, 90 + 90 = 180 degrees, 180 % 360 = 180 degrees
- 200 gon = 180 degrees, 180 + 90 = 270 degrees, 270 % 360 = 270 degrees
- 300 gon = 270 degrees, 270 + 90 = 360 degrees, 360 % 360 = 0 degrees
- 350 gon = 315 degrees, 315 + 90 = 405 degrees, 405 % 360 = 45 degrees
- 400 gon = 360 degrees, 360 + 90 = 450 degrees, 450 % 360 = 90 degrees

[image]

You can use this expression in QGIS calculator to create a new field, or use it on the fly with geometry generator to style your points/labels/etc with the correct angle.

If you come across this case again but have `"gon"` starting from a different angle relative to north, just change `90` accordingly in the above expression.

Comment: fine, that's work, thank

Answer (score 3):

If the subject is about the QGIS Field Calculator expression;

```
if("gon"<300, ("gon"+100)*0.9, ("gon"-300)*0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: nice illustration, I use this solution in first time.